# Running batch file in Win7

Tags: file, batch-file

Using batch file, I'm trying to make a call to a program called kxshell and then run kxScript using kxshell.
So in my batch file I wrote

Kxshell.exe 
Read testscript.kxs

Which means I want that cmd first calls the kxshell and then kxshell executes Read testscript.kxs

But as soon as the batch file executes the exe, it starts the kxshell prompt and doesn't run the read command. Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on `kxshell` itself and how it's written to receive arguments.

For example, `bash` under Linux executes commands with the `-c` option:

```
bash -c 'echo hello`
```

(if you just use `bash echo hello`, it will attempt to run the binary `echo` program as a script, not something you want to do).

Apparently, `kxshell` uses a similar approach, using `-e` to execute arbitrary commands:

```
kxshell -e read testscript.kxs
```

Comment: Thanks paxdiablo for your answer. Kxshell is scripting shell for running analytics using SAP InfiniteInsight. I went over the documentation as you suggested and figured out that I have to invoke the command using -e. So I ended up using 
kxshell -e read filename 
and it worked.

Comment: Okay, @Puntis, I'll incorporate that into the answer so it's useful for others as well.